# Groovy - can a method defined in an Interface have default values?

Tags: groovy, interface

If the following is entered in Eclipse/STS (with groovy):

```
interface iFaceWithAnIssue {
    def thisIsFine(a,b,c)
    def thisHasProblems(alpha='va')
}
```

The only line that complains is the one trying to use a default value.  I can not tell from the codehaus site if this is supported or not.

The IDE error is:

```
Groovy:Cannot specify default value for method parameter
```

So this makes me think it is not supported.  As there will be multiple implementations, I wanted to use an interface here.  I don't really need the default value in the interface, but there is an error trying to fulfill the interface contract if the implementation class then tries to default this argument.  Is there any way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot.

When you define a default value, Groovy actually creates multiple methods in your class, so for example:

```
class Test {
    void something( a=false ) {
        println a
    }
}
```

Actually creates

```
public void something(java.lang.Object a) {
    this.println(a)
}
```

and

```
public void something() {
    this.something(((false) as java.lang.Object))
}
```

This can't be done as it stands in Interfaces.

You could do:

```
interface iFaceWithAnIssue {
    def thisHasProblems()
    def thisHasProblems(alpha)
}
```

Then

```
class Test implements iFaceWithAnIssue {
    // This covers both Inteface methods
    def thisHasProblems(alpha='va') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - that tells what I need to do too!  I can just add the method with the default to the class and have it call the implementation of the interface's method - duh....

Comment: @JoeG Of course this will have to be revisited with Java 8's default Interface implementations